# How to accumulate results (with forEach?) in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Suppose I want to search through a collection, scan the returned result set and return some transformation of it. I've tried the following code:

```
db.my_collection.find({timestamp : {$gt: 1343032491799}}, {_id:0,sid:1}).limit(20).forEach(function(element) { print(element.sid); })
```

Ok, it worked well. To the question: how can I accumulate the results (`sid`s) into an array instead of just printing them?

*Update*: ruby-style one-liner is preferred (but not required) of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `toArray` on the cursor instead of `forEach`:

```
var a = db.my_collection.find(
    {timestamp : {$gt: 1343032491799}}, {_id:0,sid:1}).limit(20)
    .toArray().map(function(o){return o.sid;})
```

**UPDATE**

Seems you can skip the `toArray` and go right to the [`map`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/) as the cursor provides that method directly:

```
var a = db.my_collection.find(
    {timestamp : {$gt: 1343032491799}}, {_id:0,sid:1}).limit(20)
    .map(function(o){return o.sid;})
```

Comment: calling `toArray()` will return the array of objects like `{ sid: "1234" }`. I would like to get them without the `sid`, just the numbers

Comment: Can you please link to the 'map()' function? (Accepting anyway)

Comment: PS: Also, do I must to use `toArray()` or it can be skipped (and why, please)?

Comment: `map` is the standard `Array` method.  Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  Yes, `toArray` is still needed here.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried without the `toArray()` and it seems working as well. I think the cursor also have the `map` method.

Comment: @BreakPhreak Cool!  Yeah, I just tested that in the shell and it worked for me as well.  Found the docs on that [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable in the parent scope.

```
var myArr = []; //the results will go there
db.my_collection.find({timestamp : {$gt: 1343032491799}}, {_id:0,sid:1}).limit(20).forEach(function(element) {
  myArr.push(element.sid); //this function has access to myArr
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Push the id's to a array:

```
var myArray = [];
b.my_collection.find({timestamp : {$gt: 1343032491799}}, {_id:0,sid:1 })
    .limit(20)
    .forEach(function(element) {
        myArray.push(element.sid);
    })​
```